# Can I / how do I explicitly terminate a long running xhr request?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can I cause an xhr request to interrupt/terminate clientside? I have a number of long running requests, and I want to abandon them once they're no longer relevant.

Comment: A few have pointed out a significant exception to me, so figured I'd add it as a comment here: 'jsonp' and 'xhr' requests are different, despite the usually similar convenience/wrapper functions. 'jsonp' requests, as currently implemented, cannot be interrupted/terminated clientside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe [`xhr.abort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#abort%28%29) is what you're looking for.